# Rewrite word count function as OOP in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I have written a simple function for counting the occurrences of words in a sentence or phrase.

```
def count(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.lower()    
    lst = phrase.split()
    dct = dict()
    for word in lst:
        if word not in dct:
            dct[word] = 1
        else:
            dct[word] += 1
    return dct
```

Note that right now I'm not concerned with punctuation, numbers, or stopwords.

What I want to do is write a class to take an object and do the same thing. Here's what I have so far, but now I'm stuck on how to pass the list on to the loop that  counts and creates the dictionary:

```
class Count:
    dct = dict()
    def __init__(self, phrase):
         self.phrase = phrase
    def lst(self):
        return self.phrase.lower().split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use defaultdict for convenience.

```
from collections import defaultdict as ddict
class Count:
    def __init__(self, phrase):
         self.phrase = phrase
         self.dct = ddict(int)
    def lst(self):
        return self.phrase.lower().split()

    # you can do it this way
    def make_dict(self):
        lst_words = self.lst()
        for word in lst_words:
            self.dct[word] += 1

c = Count("What I want to do is write a class to take an object and do the same thing. Here's what I have so far, but now I'm stuck on how to pass the list on to the loop that counts and creates the dictionary")
c.make_dict()     # make a dictonary out of words
c.dct             # display the contents stored in the dict
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(int,
            {'what': 2,
             'i': 2,
             'want': 1,
             'to': 4,
             'do': 2,
             'is': 1,
             'write': 1,
             'a': 1,
             'class': 1,
             'take': 1,
             'an': 1,
             'object': 1,
             'and': 2,
             'the': 4,
             'same': 1,
             'thing.': 1,
             "here's": 1,
             'have': 1,
             'so': 1,
             'far,': 1,
             'but': 1,
             'now': 1,
             "i'm": 1,
             'stuck': 1,
             'on': 2,
             'how': 1,
             'pass': 1,
             'list': 1,
             'loop': 1,
             'that': 1,
             'counts': 1,
             'creates': 1,
             'dictionary': 1})
```

Update:
By the courtesy Roelant of there is one more way to do the same thing, using `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
class Count:
    def __init__(self, phrase):
         self.phrase = phrase
         self.dct = None
    def lst(self):
        return self.phrase.lower().split()

    # you can do it this way also.
    def make_dict(self):
        lst_words = self.lst()
        self.dct = Counter(lst_words)
```

Comment: Can also extend the Counter class :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Both of these methods are giving me an error for some reason:
---> 12         lst_words = lst()
NameError: name 'lst' is not defined

Comment: I got it to work for me by adding:
# you can do it this way also.
    def make_dict(self):
        lst_words = self.lst()
        self.dct = Counter(lst_words)
        return self.dct
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jabernet, if this solves your problem, you can upvote it so that it can be helpful to others as well

Comment: @taurus05 okay I did that. I may have more questions but I'll see if I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: Try them by yourself. If you face issues, share them with the community. You will be served with the best responses.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this; maybe you know this allready, but I'll put this option here anyways.

```
>>> import collections

>>> phrase = "What I want to do is write a class to take an object and do the same thing. Here's what I have so far, but now I'm stuck on how to pass the list on to the loop that counts and creates the dictionary."
>>> c = collections.Counter(phrase.lower().split())
>>> for k, v in c.most_common():
...     print(v, k)

4 to
4 the
2 what
2 i
2 do
2 and
2 on
1 want
1 is
1 write
1 a
1 class
1 take
1 an
1 object
1 same
1 thing.
1 here's
1 have
1 so
1 far,
1 but
1 now
1 i'm
1 stuck
1 how
1 pass
1 list
1 loop
1 that
1 counts
1 creates
1 dictionary.
```

There is no big advantage of wrapping this in a class, but you could have something simple like this that subclasses `Counter`:

```
import collections
import string

class MyCounter(collections.Counter):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        # do some preprocessing, for example removing puntuation
        phrase = ''.join(
            c.lower()
            for c in phrase
            if c not in string.punctuation)

        super().__init__(phrase.split())
```

The use would be similar as before:

```
>>> mc = MyCounter(phrase)         # 'lower' and 'split' is done inside
>>> for k, v in mc.most_common():
...     print(v, k)

4 to
4 the
2 what
2 i
2 do
2 and
2 on
1 want
1 is
1 write
1 a
1 class
1 take
1 an
1 object
1 same
1 thing
1 heres
1 have
1 so
1 far
1 but
1 now
1 im
1 stuck
1 how
1 pass
1 list
1 loop
1 that
1 counts
1 creates
1 dictionary
```

Comment: Intuitive solution :) Think for speed its best to use `phrase.translate(None, string.punctuation)` then `phrase.lower()` and then using a generator for the stopwords `super().__init__((x for x in phrase.split() if x not in stopwords))`. If speed is an issue anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I had not thought of `str.translate()`; it definitively is an option to achieve that.